# Objectbox issue on read - can't assign value into field

Tags: dart, objectbox

I have an object Day. List "dbLunchMenu" and "dbDinnerMenu" are the db representation of properties List "lunchMenu" and "dinnerMenu".

Objectbox failed to set my last field "dbDinnerMenu" during read operation.
If I check read implementation (file objectbox.g.dart, methodValue EntityDefinition.objectFromFB) value is ok before reading the previous field (dbLunchMenu) and not after.

I know very little about Buffer, Byte... (which all seems to much complicated) but I understand as dbLunchMenu is read, some kind of pointer is moved and dbDinnerMenu is no longer readable.

Did you guys experience something similar ? I've tried to replace List type of "dbLunchMenu" and "dbDinnerMenu" to String but nothing as changed (after uninstall, dart run build_runner build and reinstall.

[Day - properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGQ5a.png)

[Objectbox - objectToFB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrBm9.png)
"dbLunchMenu" and "dbDinnerMenu" are set on watch

[Objectbox - objectFromFB - before dbLunchMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHLHX.png)
two assignments are set on watch

[Objectbox - objectFromFB - after dbLunchMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0PFo.png)
two assignments are empty on watch

Issue seem to be on this point :

```
..dbLunchMenu = const fb.ListReader<String>(
                    fb.StringReader(asciiOptimization: true),
                    lazy: false)
                .vTableGet(buffer, rootOffset, 10, [])
```

Thanks,

Comment: This was already reported on https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/issues/550.